# Integral of $a^x$

Tags: calculus, integration

I know how to find the integral of $x^a$ (I'm using $a$ as a constant) - it's just $\frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1}$. But, how do you figure out $\int a^x$ or variations of this problem: $\int a^{x+c}$ or $\int a^{c^x}$?

Comment: Hint:   $a^x=\exp(x\ln a)$

Comment: Also, here's a hard one: $\int (x+1)^{\large e+1}\mathrm de =$? And yes, it's $de$ there.

Comment: @ㄴㄱ is the answer to that question: $\frac {(x+1)^{e+2}}{e+1}$? If no, why not?

Comment: I can't see how you arrived at $\frac {(x+1)^{e+2}}{e+1}$, if it was $dx$ instead then you would've had $\frac {(x+1)^{e+2}}{e+2}+c$. That's because $\int (x+y)^n dx =\frac{(x+y)^{n+1}}{n+1}+c$.

But with $de$ it's quite painful to work since we're often used to think that $e$ is that constant, but in this case $e$ is a variable.

See, if you can get the answer using:
$\int k^t dt=\frac{k^t}{\ln k}+c$.

Comment: Do you just plug in (x+1) as k and e+1 as t?

Comment: You get the right answer doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $a^x=e^{x\log a}$,$$\int a^x\,\mathrm dx=\frac{e^{x\log a}}{\log a}=\frac{a^x}{\log a}.$$

Comment: To the editor: "$\log$" means base $e$ in math beyond elementary calculus.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of $a^x$ is $a^x\times ln(a)$. It follows that the antiderivative is $\frac{a^x}{ln(a)}$.

Comment: Why is the derivative of $a^x$ equal to $a^x\ln a$?

Comment: It is well known that $(e^x)'=e^x$. And we have $a^x=e^{xln(a)}$. So by the chain rule $(a^x)'=e^{xln(a)}ln(a)=a^xln(a)$.